# How to identify queries that cause high Logical I/O?

Tags: sql-server

I need some help to identify SQL queries that could suddenly increase the SQL Server Logical I/O.

Can someone please help to provide some advice? This was from SQL Server 2017
[image]

Comment: These will help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/correlate-a-trace-with-windows-performance-log-data?view=sql-server-ver15.  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/correlating-sql-server-profiler-with-performance-monitor/.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4579/associate-a-sql-profiler-trace-with-performance-monitor-data/

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment, so posting here.  Below query should get you started:

```
SELECT 
      qs.total_logical_reads
    , qs.total_logical_writes
    , qs.total_physical_reads
    , qs.last_logical_reads
    , qs.last_logical_writes
    , ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid), 'Ad-hoc Query') [Proc Name]
    , st.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
ORDER BY (qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes) DESC
```

Note - the totals are cumulative over time, so careful of the "gotchas" of queries which have been using little IO each execution but have been executed frequently over longer period of time versus queries which just started using more IO and/or executing more frequently. Check out more info about [sys.dm_exec_query_stats and other potentially useful queries on the MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Another option is to install Brent Ozar's first responder kit - or just sp_blitzCache if you can't install everything - and run EXEC [dbo].[sp_BlitzCache] @SortOrder = 'reads'